# Vista Explorer - how to show a column in Details View for a folder and all its subfolders?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

In Vista, when you open a folder in Detail View it shows some default columns like "Name", "Date modified", "Type" and "Size". It is also possible to add other columns like "Categories". But this column gets added to the folder view only in the current folder. Is it possible to set it to be displayed for subfolders as well?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

In Windows Explorer, click the **Organize** button and on the menu, click the **Folder and Search Options** item.

[image]

Which brings up the **Folder Options** dialog:

[image]

On the **View** tab, in the **Folder Views** section, click the **Apply to Folders** button.

Comment: Of course this approach resets *all* folders, not just the current folder and children.